# Center elements and put them in column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 and have created the following form.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
       <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="height:100vh;">
                        <h1>My header tagline.</h1>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <form action=""
                                      enctype="multipart/form-data"
                                      method="POST">
                                    <div class="form-inline">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" value=""
                                               placeholder="Enter your Email">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary">enter</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

However, I would like to center the text and show it below like that:

[image]

Any recommendation what is wrong with my css?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: add `flex-column` to the element where you have `d-flex`

Answer (score -1):

You want to achieve this?

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
       <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="height:100vh;">
                        <div class="row">
                          <h1>My header tagline.</h1>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <form action=""
                                      enctype="multipart/form-data"
                                      method="POST">
                                    <div class="form-inline">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" value=""
                                               placeholder="Enter your Email">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary">enter</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```